# Abrir Pasta para selecionar arquivo

Tags: java

Como eu faço para abrir a caixa de seleção de arquivo e somente escolher músicas com a extensão `.mp3`?

Estou utilizando o Windowbuilder mas o menu não disponibiliza tal opção para criação rápida.

Comment: Poste o seu código para que a comunidade possa analisar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html. Bom, creio que esse seja o caminho das pedras para a sua dúvida.

Comment: Apesar de um pouco mal formulada a pergunta, é possível responder sim dentro do contexto perguntado. Por isto votei pra deixar em aberto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme estas ambas respostas encontradas no *SOen*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202891/1518921
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31874587/1518921

### Adicionando o `JFileChooser`

Aparentemente `JFileChooser` não esta presente por padrão, mas você pode adicionar, siga os passos:

1. Vá até `system` e clique em `Choose Component`:

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>
2. Agora busque pelo seu componente o adicione.

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>

### Selecionando os tipos de arquivos

Vai precisar do método `getDescription` e `accept`, exemplo:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
{
   public String getDescription() {
       return "Audio Files (*.mp3)";
   }

   public boolean accept(File f) {
       if (f.isDirectory()) {
           return true;
       } else {
           String filename = f.getName().toLowerCase();
           return filename.endsWith(".mp3");
       }
   }
});
```

Ainda não testei o código, mas parece funcionar, por favor se houver qualquer problema me comunique.